# Data Structure: Returning the same shaped BST with another BST's values

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Hey I have a question where I need to describe an algorithm that gets 2 Binary Search Trees, T1 and T2. The trees contain different values for each node.
And the algorithm should return a Binary Search Tree with the same shape as T2, but with values of T1 with time complexity of `O(n)` where `n` is the number of elements (same for both trees)

what we call "Equally Topological" (I think this is how it's called / A nice name for that)

For example:

T1 (defined the values)

[image: T1 Image]

T2 (defined the shape):

[image: T2 Image]

Should Return:

[image: The Resault]

What I've tried so far is to think about the median value / average however that does not work each time, or think about maybe building an AVL tree then rotating it until we find the solution but I don't have in mind if that would work, or is of time complexity `O(n)`. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traverse T1 and write values to an array (in sorted order they will be). Then create a copy of T2 (if necessary) and traverse it, writing values from array one by one. This will use 2 traversals, so it is Θ(n). Traverse both trees in order left subtree - vertex - right subtree.

Comment: You are a genius sir!